# Is there a Ruby or Rails way to extract only a particular argument option similar to #extract_options!, but without the destructive part?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, wrapper

I often times write wrappers around Rails helpers, such as `#link_to`.  So, I want to pass most of the arguments to the actual Rails helper with something like this:

```
def wrapper_link_to(*args, &blk)
  ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(*args, &blk)
end
```

Because I don't want to reimplement all the cool stuff that `#link_to` (or `#content_for` or lower) already does.

Is there a way to pull certain arguments out of `*args` before passing it along?  That way I can interact with only the arguments the wrapper method cares about and still keep all the rest of `#link_to` working?

I want to do something like this:

```
def wrapper_link_to(wrapper_arg, *args, &blk)
  options = args.extract_option!(:wrapper_option) # extract_options! would normally clear out args
  if options[:wrapper_option]
    # do stuff
  end
  ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(wrapper_arg || other_stuff, more_stuff, *args, &blk) # *args will now be the original *args, but without :wrapper_option
end
```

Right now, I've copied the logic of #extract_options! and made an ugly method that's like:

```
def extract_option(arg, args)
  if args.last.is_a?(Hash) && args.last.extractable_options?
    args_hash = args.pop
    args_value = args_hash.extract!(arg)[arg]
    return args_value, [args_hash]
  else
    return nil, args
  end
end
```

Is there a Ruby or Rails method that does something similar to this already?

Ultimately, it would be nice if:

```
wrappper_option_value = args.extract_option!(:wrapper_option)
```

Would modify `args` to have the the `:wrapper_option` removed and return the value of `:wrapper_option`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the other_stuff and more_stuff is in your example. But after separating args from options with `extract_options!` you could use the :wrapper_option value then just delete it with options.delete(:wrapper_option) before calling `link_to`. If I understand correctly what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can write it your self (note there is no bang "!" to have a different method name):

```
def extract_options
  last.is_a?(::Hash) ? last : {}
end
```

or you could `extract_option!` from a duplicate, leaving your original `args` untouched

```
def wrapper_link_to(wrapper_arg, *args, &blk)
  options = args.dup.extract_option!(:wrapper_option)
  ...
end
```